# Antivirus: pros and cons of quarantine and deleting (ClamAV particularity). Clean option

Tags: antivirus, malware

What are the pros and cons of qurantine and deleting in an antivirus? Does ClamAV have some particularity on this point? Also, is there some antivirus or anti-malware which allows to clean the infected file? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With quarantine, you can check the status of your quarantined items, restore or delete individual quarantined items, or simply empty the whole quarantine.

so if you found a false positive you can restore it.

This FQA is helpful: http://clamtk.sourceforge.net/faq.html

All antivirus does clean infected files with different degree based on the type of malware.